# Cannot add phpMyAdmin Cartridge on OpenShift Application

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, openshift, scalability

I have added a MySQL 5.5 cartridge to my scalable application in OpenShift. However, when I try to add phpMyAdmin 4.0 to my application after adding the MySQL 5.5 cartridge, I get the following error:

```
phpmyadmin-4 cannot be embedded in scalable app '...'.
```

I tried to add the phpMyAdmin 4.0 cartridge after adding the MySQL 5.1 cartridge, but that didn't work either, and I received the same error.

Is there a work around/solution to this?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: try: http://topnew.net/sidu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on the cartridge, and in the error message that you posted above, the phpmyadmin cartridge is not compatible with scaled applications.  You could try using port forwarding and setup something like mysql workbench locally to connect to your database.